# How to display a usercontrol in a thread of WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-controls

I have a wpf project with several `Threads` and I also have a `Usercontrol` with `progressbar`and `TextBlock` to indicate the progress of Thread. My codes are as follows:

**XAML:**

```
<Button Command="{Binding Start}" /> //This button start the thread
```

**ViewModel:**

```
private ICommand _start;
public ICommand Start
{
    get
    {
        if(_start == null)
        {
            _start = new RelayCommand(
            param => Start_Thread());
        }

        return _start;
    }
}

private void Start_Thread()
{
      ...//Some irrelevant juedgement codes here
      Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartSample));
      t.Start();
}
```

SO in the `StartSample` thread, I want to popup a `Usercontrol` to indicate the current progress.

**Usercontrol XAML:**

```
<UserControl 
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Info, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" />
     <mui:ModernProgressRing Style="{StaticResource RotatingPlaneProgressRingStyle}" IsActive="True" />
</UserControl>
```

SO what should I do popup the `UserControl` while the main thread is running. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `UserControl`s don't "pop up". You can display then in some other container, in a variety of ways (e.g. modify their `Visibility` property, set a bound content property, etc.). That a thread is involved is hardly relevant; as long as you're using standard data binding practices, WPF will handle the cross-thread aspect for you. If you want a good answer from Stack Overflow, you need to improve the question. Provide a good [mcve] showing what you've tried, and explain _specifically_ what you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show a new window with the `UserControl` on the UI thread in it *before* you start the long-running operation on a background thread and then close the window once the operation has completed.

The recommended and easiest way of doing this would be to use the [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl):

```
private void Start_Thread()
{
    Window win = new Window();
    win.Content = new YourUserControl();
    win.Show();

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Sample_Thread();
    }).ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        //this code runs back on the UI thread once the task has finished
        win.Close();
    }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```